# Mathematica Lab

Tags: taylor-expansion, mathematica

1. For each of the following functions and associated points, P, compute the equation of the
   Taylor quadratic approximation to the function at P. Graph the original surface and its Taylor
   approximation on the same set of axes, and identify each surface.
   (a) z = sin(xy), P = (1, PI/2)
   (b) z = exp(–x^2 – y^2), P = (0.3, 0.4)

**How would I plot this in Mathematica**

Comment: You may be more likely to get a response if you read Mathematica's documentation first and then post your attempt.

Comment: I agree with @Benjamin. A little hint, though, Taylor approximation is obtained using function Series[...]

Answer (score 0):

```
func[z_, x0_, y0_] := Total[({z, D[z, x], D[z, y], D[z, {x, 2}], D[z, x, y], D[z, {y, 2}]} /. {x -> x0, y -> y0})*{1, (x - x0), (y - y0), (x - x0)^2/2, (x - x0) (y - y0), (y - y0)^2/2}];

Plot3D[{Sin[x y], Evaluate[func[Sin[x y], 1, Pi/2]]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, Pi/2 - 1, Pi/2 + 1}, PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"Function", "Approximation"}]]

Plot3D[{Exp[-x^2 - y^2], Evaluate[func[Exp[-x^2 - y^2], 0.3, 0.4]]}, {x, 0.3 - 1, 0.3 + 1}, {y, 0.4 - 1, 0.4 + 1}, PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"Function", "Approximation"}]]
```

The first line defines a function that returns the quadratic Taylor approximation to `z` around `x0`,`y0`.
`Series` isn't a *perfect* way to do this, since

`Normal[Series[z, {x, x0, 2}, {y, y0, 2}]]`

will end up having terms proportional to ${\Delta x}^{2}{\Delta y}$, ${\Delta x}{\Delta y}^{2}$, and ${\Delta x}^{2}{\Delta y}^{2}$.

(`Normal` just removes the big-O notation, turning the series into the corresponding approximation.)

The second and third lines do the actual plotting. Assuming you are using the default colors, the 'true' function will be orange, while the approximation will be blue.